# Undefined type 'App\Http\Middleware\Auth'

Tags: php, laravel

i am new to laravel and i am trying to make an admin dashboard but in the adminmiddleware file i am having this error with both of my Auth

```
Undefined type 'App\Http\Middleware\Auth'
```

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            if (Auth::user()->role_as == '1') {
                return $next($request);
            } else {
                return redirect('/home')->with('status', 'Access denied! as you are not an admin');
            }
        } else {
            return redirect('/home')->with('status', ' pleaselogin first');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The answers below have it; namespacing issue. But, there's also a global method `auth()` that does the same thing; `auth()->user()` is equivalent to `Auth::user()` and doesn't require importing the `Auth` facade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

before

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Answer (score 0):

either use the Auth facade from the global namespace: \Auth,

or (better) add its FQCN in your use declarations:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;